# Undefine reference for libraries, so How could I find the right path?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, v4l2

I am trying to compile a v4l2 example in Ubuntu but I am getting the following error:

```
guilherme@notedev01:~/Downloads/V4l2_samples-0.4.1$ make
gcc -O2  -L/usr/include -lX11 -lXext -o viewer viewer.c
/tmp/ccUjnjWQ.o: In function `image_destroy':
viewer.c:(.text+0x234): undefined reference to `XDestroyImage'
viewer.c:(.text+0x256): undefined reference to `XFreeGC'
viewer.c:(.text+0x277): undefined reference to `XShmDetach'
viewer.c:(.text+0x2ac): undefined reference to `XFreePixmap'
/tmp/ccUjnjWQ.o: In function `image_create':
viewer.c:(.text+0x305): undefined reference to `XCreateGC'
viewer.c:(.text+0x31d): undefined reference to `XGetWindowAttributes'
viewer.c:(.text+0x39e): undefined reference to `XShmCreateImage'
viewer.c:(.text+0x3f5): undefined reference to `XShmAttach'
viewer.c:(.text+0x44e): undefined reference to `XCreateImage'
viewer.c:(.text+0x494): undefined reference to `XShmQueryExtension'
viewer.c:(.text+0x4b4): undefined reference to `XShmPixmapFormat'
viewer.c:(.text+0x4dc): undefined reference to `XShmCreatePixmap'
/tmp/ccUjnjWQ.o: In function `image_put':
viewer.c:(.text+0x54c): undefined reference to `XPutImage'
viewer.c:(.text+0x586): undefined reference to `XShmPutImage'
/tmp/ccUjnjWQ.o: In function `main':
viewer.c:(.text.startup+0x18b): undefined reference to `XOpenDisplay'
viewer.c:(.text.startup+0x1b1): undefined reference to `XScreenOfDisplay'
viewer.c:(.text.startup+0x1ee): undefined reference to `XCreateSimpleWindow'
viewer.c:(.text.startup+0x249): undefined reference to `XMapRaised'
viewer.c:(.text.startup+0x263): undefined reference to `XStoreName'
viewer.c:(.text.startup+0x280): undefined reference to `XGetWindowAttributes'
viewer.c:(.text.startup+0x92f): undefined reference to `XPending'
viewer.c:(.text.startup+0x94c): undefined reference to `XNextEvent'
viewer.c:(.text.startup+0xaee): undefined reference to `XPending'
viewer.c:(.text.startup+0xb0b): undefined reference to `XNextEvent'
viewer.c:(.text.startup+0xf39): undefined reference to `XPending'
viewer.c:(.text.startup+0xf56): undefined reference to `XNextEvent'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [viewer] Error 1
```

What I can see is that the path for -lx11 and -lXext isn't -L/usr/include.
How can I find the right path for those libraries?

Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

as Chris has pointed out, the order is wrong, you need to put the `-lX11 -lXext` after the source-code/object-files.

this is because modern compilers try to optimize the final result and not link against unused libraries.
they do so by maintaining a list of unresolved symbols within an object and use any binary files that come *aferwards* in the linker arguments to resolve those symbols.

### example

your program *test* uses the function `do_foo()` from *libfoo* and the function `do_bar_do()` from *libbar*.

you link it using:

```
$ gcc -o test test.o -lfoo -lbar
```

the linker first searches `test.o` and notices that some symbols (`do_foo` and `do_bar_do`) are not defined anywhere. it then proceeds to `libfoo` (specified right after `test.o`) and finds that it provides `do_foo`, so it creates code to use it from your program. `do_bar_do` is still unresolved, until the linker checks upon `libbar`.

consider doing it the wrong way:

```
$ gcc -o test -lfoo test.o -lbar
```

the linker will first check `libfoo` and see that it doesn't contain any unresolved symbols. cool. it will then proceed to `test.o` and notice `do_bar_do` and `do_foo`. `do_bar_do` is resolved by the right-hand `libbar` but `do_foo` is not resolved at all, and you get an error:

> undefined reference to `do_foo'

### "but the code is meant to be a tutorial..."

so why is it not working?

older compilers where a bit lax about the order of dependencies (they would check all binaries/libraries/objects whether a given symbol could be resolved); that's why you can still find code out there that puts the libraries to link against *before* the object files.

Answer (score 2):

The `-lX11 -lXext` must come *after* the `viewer.c` in the command line (and should probably be in the order `-lXext -lX11`). Also, ensure that the `libx11-6-dev` and `libxext6-dev` packages are installed.

System libraries are usually in `/lib` and `/usr/lib`, and you do not need to use `-L` to specify those directories.